# How do I completely remove Tor from OSX Yosemite?

Tags: mac

I installed Tor Browser to see what all the hype was about and now my computer is messed up.

I can't reboot the computer, it won't load. It sits on the apple gray screen for hours. Everything worked fine before I installed Tor.

I removed Tor Browser with App Zapper and it still won't boot. I've been to the apple store and the genius bar checked everything and the hardware is fine, its a problem with the OS.

I even reinstalled OSX Yosemite and it still doesn't work. Can anybody help me remove all the stuff that Tor installed that's messed up my computer.

Tor is garbage. I'd rather be raided by the NSA than have my computer not work.

Answer (score 3):

So it's garbage because it didn't work on your mac? Reinstalling the whole OS should wipe the stuff Tor installed on system files (in case any changes to system has been made). The problem sounds like a dead or dying hard drive. Just an app like Tor won't render computers unbootable. It works great on my mavericks installation.